# Why npm install && npm run dev , doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

i am making new laravel "v.6" application and i use auth , i already download composer `require laravel/ui  --dev`, but when I write the second command which is `php artisan ui bootstrap--auth` it show me that I have install "npm install & npm run dev", but npm didn't install it show me error

**So how to fix it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//in Laravel 6

composer require laravel/ui:^1.0 --dev

php artisan ui bootstrap --auth

npm install && npm run dev